# Как взаимодействовать с виртуализированными элементами ListView?

Tags: android, listview, виртуализация

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на `Item` `ListView`, значение альфа-канала всех других `Item`'ов устанавливалось равным `0.5`. Пробовал реализовать это через цикл:

```
for (int a = 0; a < lv.getChildCount(); a++) {
    lv.getChildAt(a).setAlpha(0.5f);
}
```

Но при нажатии на `Item` приложение вылетает с логом:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setAlpha(float)' on a null object reference
```

То есть: с теми `Item`'ами, которых не видно на экране, нельзя ничего сделать (их нет).

Как тогда такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения таких проблем придумали адаптер=)

```
public class SomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ArrayList<SomeClass> myList;
private class ViewHolder{
    TextView tv1;
    ImageView iv1;
}
public SomeAdapter(Context mCon, ArrayList<SomeClass> list){
    this.myList = list;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCon);
    this.context = mCon;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myList.size();
}

@Override
public ProfileEntry getItem(int position) {
    return myList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder = null;
if (convertView == null){
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_profile,null);
    //находим элементы в разметке, но не меняем их
    holder.tv1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_profileRow1);
    holder.iv1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_profileRow1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    //тут назначаем свойства разметке в зависимости от данных
    if (myList.get(position).getSomeMethod().equals("Что-то")){
 // прописываем какой-то текст            
 holder.tv1.setText("Укажите город");
 //устанавливаем картинку
        int picId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(myList.get(position).getImage(),"drawable",context.getPackageName());
        holder.iv1.setImageResource(picId);
    }else{
        holder.tv1.setText(myList.get(position).getAnotherMethod());
        int picId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(myList.get(position).getImage(),"drawable",context.getPackageName());
        holder.iv1.setImageResource(picId);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Не надо пытаться менять элементы разметки списков не из адаптера.

1. Заведите в адаптере `int` переменную для хранения позиции нажатого элемента.
2. При нажатии на элемент задавайте значение этой переменной
3. В `getView` в зависимости от того, совпадает текущая позиция о значением этой переменной или нет задавайте прозрачность разметке элемента.

В классе адаптера:

```
private int selectedPosition = -1;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    if(position==selectedPosition) {//делаем непрозрачным}
    else{//делаем прозрачным}
    //тут вешаем слушатель нажатий где меняем значение selectedPosition
}
```

Comment: Можно приблизительный код?

Comment: @СергейГрушин, чего-то написал.

Comment: Странно, не выполняется слушатель `OnItemClickListener`. Мне он нужен.

Comment: @СергейГрушин, покажите в коде, как вы его задали.

Comment: @СергейГрушин, нельзя одновременно слушатели вешать в getView и на адаптер снаружи. Вам надо выбрать один из способов. Правильный - отказаться от `onItemClickListener`, т.к. его нет в улучшенном ListView - RecyclerView. Если же хотите делать неправильно - то задавайте значение переменной из onItemClickListenera объекту адаптера сеттером

Comment: @Ivan Vovk, в слушателе на список  `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){ @Override  public void OnItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id){ ..... }});` в адаптере я даю id корневому `layout` и вешаю на него слушатель `rootLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ @Override public void onClick(View itemView) { ... }});`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, немного оффтопа. Вы отказались полностью от использования в своих программах от ListView, ну то есть заменили на recycleview?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, идиотизм какой-то :(((( ладно, ну эти адаптеры

Comment: @IvanVovk, да, уже около 2 лет ListView не трогаю и счастлив)

Comment: @СергейГрушин, зря через адаптер все решается! просто надо подойти утром со свежей головой и чистой совестью)

Comment: @Ivan Vovk, я с `ListView` ничего не могу сделать, с `RecyclerView` вообще с ума сойду. Это какой-то бред, как вообще списки эти долбаные делать. Меня уже достало это все. Ненавижу списки

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, из-за долбаной прозрачности так мозг ломать. И с `ListView` не сойду - боюсь учить `RecyclerView` - он сложный

Comment: @СергейГрушин, просто уберите слушатель снаружи адаптера и всё.